# Перетаскивание формы авторизации мышью

Tags: jquery, javascript, html

Всем привет. Сделал форму авторизации. Меня интересует такой вопрос, как сделать так, чтобы форму авторизации можно было перемешать мышью. Что для этого необходимо подключить? Какие функции использовать? Готовый код принимается. Я постараюсь разобраться. Спасибо, заранее, за ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JQuery-ui draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) - думать почти не надо. Качаем, пользуемся.